# Azure DevOps - export project user permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to export or get in e.g. json file a list of users with their permission per project in my organization.

I was looking in Azure DevOps REST Api reference ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 ) but with no luck. Also checked Azure DevOps cli.

Do you have any idea how can I get a list of user permission per project?

Comment: Have you looked into the permission reports from the Rest API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport

Comment: @danielom I noticed it but I need to get a list of user permissions. The permission reports contains only group permissions.